# Key automatically reset each time I hit save in Azure Devops Project Service Connection Settings

Tags: azure-devops

we have a service connection set up for our project to access resources in azure cloud. Once the service connection secret has expired(after two years), we decided to delete the old secret and create a new secret in the service principal itself and save the new secret generated.

The problem is, if i dont click edit in the service principal and save, it will not pick up the new secret generated and if i click edit and save, seems like service connection itself will generate a new secret by itself and i cant get the value of the new secret from the service principal.

Is there any workaround whether to stop the service connection resetting/creating a new secret by itself or retrieve the secret value that is created by the service connection(since when i see in the service principal itself, the value is masked)

I tried :
a) creating the secret itself, which is overwritten by the service connection when i click edit > save